# How do I show a % complete in Grafana (how many of my servers are up-to-ate)

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I am using prometheus and grafana to monitor several servers. I have a metric set up that will pass a value of 1 if a folder on the server is up-to-date (it's hash matches the control server's hash for that folder) and a 0 if it isn't.
When I trigger updates I'd like to be able to check grafana to see how many of the servers have updated.
My metric includes 4 labels that refer to which instance, type, folder and server they are referring to. So far I haven't been able to find anything that will allow me to show a pie chart or a guage that shows 4/6 (for example) as updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that has worked perfectly for my needs. By adding in the label value I have managed to get exactly what I am looking for - count(metric{label="test"}==1) and the equivalent ==0 - Thanks Marcelo

Comment: Great! Could you "accept" the answer and, maybe upvote it?